# Finding mean of previous set of grouped data with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a minimal working example of some data I'm working with.

```
set.seed(42)

value <- sample(1:10, 10)
group <- rep(700, each= 10)
order <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(value, group, order))

    value group order
1     10   700     1
2      9   700     1
3      3   700     1
4      6   700     2
5      4   700     2
6      8   700     2
7      5   700     2
8      1   700     2
9      2   700     2
10     7   700     2
```

I would like to group by both 'group' and 'order' and then find the mean of the values lagged by 'order'. Ideally this would produce a data frame that looks like

```
    value group order mean
1     10   700     1   NA
2      9   700     1   NA
3      3   700     1   NA
4      6   700     2  7.33
5      4   700     2  7.33
6      8   700     2  7.33
7      5   700     2  7.33
8      1   700     2  7.33
9      2   700     2  7.33
10     7   700     2  7.33
```

I'm using `dplyr` and `group_by` but I cannot figure out a way to use `mutate` and `mean()` to refer to the previous group.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit tricky because once you group your data by some variable(s) you cannot easily access other groups' data unless you refer to the original data set (like using `df$...` again but then again you don't have right groups you're looking for). There may be more direct ways that I'm missing but here's a potential dplyr-based approach to the problem:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group, order) %>%           # group the data
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%    # summarise with mean per group & order
  mutate(mean = lag(mean)) %>%         # get the previous group's mean
  right_join(df)                       # join to original data

# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# Groups: group [?]
# 
#    group order     mean value
#    (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)
# 1    700     1       NA    10
# 2    700     1       NA     9
# 3    700     1       NA     3
# 4    700     2 7.333333     6
# 5    700     2 7.333333     4
# 6    700     2 7.333333     8
# 7    700     2 7.333333     5
# 8    700     2 7.333333     1
# 9    700     2 7.333333     2
# 10   700     2 7.333333     7
```

Comment: One data.table analogue (I think): `df[df[, mean(value), by=order][, v := shift(V1)], on="order", m := v, by=.EACHI]`

Comment: @Frank, indeed, very nice

Comment: Thank you both, both of these solutions do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

We could do this with `base R`.  Create a `vector` of `unique` elements in 'order'.  Then, loop through the sequence of elements in 'Un1', subset the 'df' ('x1'), get the `Mean` value based on the subset of previous 'value' elements, create a column of 'Mean' in the dataset and `rbind` the output.

```
Un1 <- unique(df$order)
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(Un1), function(i) {
      x1 <- df[df$order==Un1[i],]
      Mean=mean(df[df$order==Un1[i-1],1])
      transform(x1,Mean=Mean) }))
```